# Difference between System.out.println(true) and System.out.println("true")

Tags: java, coding-style, system.out

Is there any difference between

```
System.out.println(true);
```

and

```
System.out.println("true");
```

Although the output I see is the same, is there any difference with respect to usage or coding style?

Comment: Speaking about coding-style, I would do #2. But since you are printing a boolean value (that comes from a boolean variable I suppose), I would call `System.out.println(myBoolVariable);`. It's not clear what would be the real use case of your suggestion. You shouldn't bother about this and let the appropriate overloaded method be called.

Answer (score 5):

In the first option you pass a `boolean` to the `PrintWriter`'s `println` method while in the second you are passing a `String`, so different `println` methods are called. In the end, the `boolean` in the first case is converted to a `String`, so the end result is the same.

If you only print a single boolean literal, `println(true)` is shorter. If you combine that literal with other `String`s, `println("value = true")` would make more sense than `println("value="+true)`.

Comment: In case of `println("value="+true)`what argument are we passing to the println method?

Comment: @Leo You would be passing a `String`, since `true` would be converted to `String` and concatenated to `"value="` before being passed to `println`.

Answer (score 4):

true gives boolean value and "true" means charsequence or string value

Answer (score 2):

The PrintWriter's println() method is overriden for many objects and primitives.

If you look internally it uses

```
write(String.valueOf(obj));
```

so the `obj.toString()` is what does all the magic :)

Answer (score 0):

Both are different 
true is boolean literal 
And 
"true" is String literal